# Javascript mailto with passing values from table on specific row

Tags: javascript, mailto

I have a working bootstrap table displaying JSON data and I have on the last column a few glyphicon with custom javascrip functions. I can successfully get a javscript function to do mailto opening clients local mail client to send an email however I want to be able to pass the values of the row selected in the mailto function in BOTH ( Subject field and body ).

Working mailto function

```
<script>

        function EmailSME() {

        var email = '<"insert SME email Address">';
        var subject ='Sample text here';
        var emailBody = 'Hi Sample,';

        document.location = "mailto:"+email+"subject="+subject+"&body="+emailBody;
      }

    </script>
```

Java script function used when a gylficon is click on the column i the table

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
                    function actionFormatter(value, row, index)
                    {
                        return [                        
                            '<a class="edit ml10" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Edit">',
                            '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>',
                            '</a>',
                            ' ',
                            '<a class="notifications ml10" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Notifications">',
                            '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></i>',
                            '</a>',
                            ' ',
                            '<a class="email ml10" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Email">',
                            '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i>'

                        ].join('');
                    }
    window.actionEvents = {
'click .email': function (e, value, row, index) {
                        $('.modalClick4').trigger('click');
                        console.log(value, row, index);

                // mailto code needs to go in here and passing the value of the specific row in the subject email       

                    }
                }
```

I know values for the selected row is working as per the console.log I can confirm the values are being passed.

A thing to note, when I click on the glyphicon"email" it triggers a Modal where I then have 3 buttons. The first button is the mailto function im trying to achieve here.

Button in Modal

```
<button onclick="EmailSME()" class="btn">  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            Email SME Template</button>
```

Comment: I believe you are missing a `?` from your `document.location` assignment.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing a `?` from your `document.location` assignment.

Try changing the first script block to:

```
<script>

  function EmailSME() {

    var email = '<"insert SME email Address">';
    var subject ='Sample text here';
    var emailBody = 'Hi Sample,';

    document.location = "mailto:"+email+"?subject="+subject+"&body="+emailBody;
  }

</script>
```

Comment: How do I pass the value of the row in the subject var ?

Comment: This will set the subject to 'Sample text here' (the value of the `subject` variable), if you want use a text input or something else, you will need to create an input with an ID in HTML and then use `document.getElementByClassName('mySubjectField').value`

Answer (score 0):

You missed `?`.
And you have to use `encodeURIComponent()` function.

```
<script>

  function EmailSME() {

    var email = '<"insert SME email Address">';
    var subject ='Sample text here';
    var emailBody = 'Hi Sample,';

    document.location = "mailto:"+encodeURIComponent(email)+"?subject="+encodeURIComponent(subject)+"&body="+encodeURIComponent(emailBody);
  }

</script>
```

Comment: im trying to get the value of that row with my email function but not successfully. how can I include the value? when I put this i get undefined in the subject 
var x = document.getElementsByName('').value;
var subject ='Sample text here'+x;

Comment: @LetsTalkAboutIt Which value do you get?